# Перстал работать код. В чем может быть ошибка?

Tags: htmlspecialchars

Файл semantic.txt - текстовой файл с кириллицей и латиницей, представляющий из себя 1тыс строк текста на кириллице. Задача кода - вывести 15 случайных строк из текстового файла, предварительно перемешав строки. Нижеприведенный код еще месяц назад работал нормально. Но, сейчас почему-то перестал работать. В чем может быть причина?

```
<?php
$arr = file('https://site.ru/themes/semantic.txt');
shuffle($arr);
$res = array_slice($arr, 0, 15);
foreach($res as $str){
  echo htmlspecialchars($str);
}
?>
```

Comment: Что значит «перестал работать»? Что происходит вместо работы?

Comment: раньше отдавал 15 строк текста из файла. а сейчас вообще ничего. пусто. если заменить в echo htmlspecialchars($str); на echo ($str); то выдает строки, но в корявой кодировке. но мне надо чтобы выводил русские тексты.

Answer (score 0):

Не могу предположить, что у вас там, но тем не менее, у меня работает как вы описали. Выводит 15 строк. Cкорее всего, кодировка файла изменена, попробуйте так:

```
<?php
$arr = file('http://localhost/semantic.txt');
shuffle($arr);
$res = array_slice($arr, 0, 15);
foreach($res as $str){
    $tempStr = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($str));
    echo htmlspecialchars($tempStr, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
?>
```

Comment: попробовал изменить версию PHP. стал отдавать строки в корявой кодировке. потом вставил ваш код. тоже отдает в корявой кодировке

Comment: https://xcoz.ru/wp-content/uploads/semantic.txt пример файла с текстом пример страницы с отдаваемыми 15-ю строками https://xcoz.ru/vkusnye-i-prostye-salaty-na-skoruyu-ruku-20-reczeptov/